# calling out radio buttons text python

Tags: python

i want to call out the name of the options,like " You have selected G " but it seems to have errors

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Xavier_\Downloads\gui.py.py", line 21, in sel
    selection = "You have selected " + str(text.get())
NameError: global name 'text' is not defined


def sel():
   selection = "You have selected " + str(text.get())
   label.config(text = selection)


var = IntVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="G", variable=var, value=1,
                  command=sel)
```

Comment: Aer we supposed to guess the error you get? You need to include it in your question!

Comment: @ThiefMaster edited.sorry,i am new here

Comment: No problem, but in general: **Always** include all necessary information when asking people about an error. This is not specific to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text` in your code isn't a variable, It's an option of the Radiobutton(), the value that you get is your `var` variable, and it's a Int, not a text.

I think you want do something like this:

```
def sel():
   selection = "You have selected " + str(v.get())
   label.config(text= selection)


v = StringVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="G", variable=v, value="G",
                  command=sel)
```

I've changed the var name because I don't like to use it,  it's reserved in some laguages.